# Solr date range and specific date

Tags: solr

I index some data include date in solr
but when search for specific date, i get some record (not all record) include some record in next day for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select/?q=pubdate:[2010-03-25T00:00:00Z TO 2010-03-25T23:59:59Z]&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&sort=pubdate desc
```

I have 625000 record in 2010-03-25 but above query result return 325412 that include 14 record from 2010-03-26.

Also I try with below query, but not get right result

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select/?q=pubdate:"2010-03-25T00:00:00Z"&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&sort=pubdate
desc
```

How to get right result for specific date?

Could you please help me?

Comment: how far into the next day? and are the ones missing from the morning hours? Sounds like a time zone issue.

Comment: As Thilo says, this is very likely a timezone issue. Remember that Solr uses UTC date/times. What are you using to index your documents?

Comment: Thanks for reply, Docs stored date fields with ISO 8601 format.means when i insert from .Net, convert to "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ". and when i search data in solr, i just search whis this format. therefore i think not time zone issue. What do you think ?

Comment: @Hamid: can you check what datetimes actually look like as stored in Solr? (I know it's that format, but I mean the actual *time*).

Comment: Thanks Mauricio, really can't, because i not store date on server, but i test for some record in local pc and it's store correctly.
Note: i using tdate field type 
<fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

Comment: strange, I see only 5 day of my index has error, that when i update again some record, it's ok, I don't know really what's problem and why my index (maybe) corrupt for some days. any how thanks a lot for response